# How to fetch thousands of database records efficiently using JPA 2 and QueryDSL?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Currently I have an implementation which fetches 10 thousand records withing 10-12 seconds. Performance of this query can be improved and how ? Following is my code snippet based on QueryDSL and JPA 2.

```
public List<EntryEntity> getEntries() {

QEntryEntity qEntryEntity = QEntryEntity.entryEntity;

return queryfactory.selectFrom(qEntryEntity).orderBy(qEntryEntity.name.asc()).fetch();
}
```

Comment: What keeps you from doing this with plain SQL?

Comment: If that **orderBy(qEntryEntity.name.asc())** ordering is done by java, It takes about 3 minutes to fetch data from local machine database.

Comment: I have a specific requirement from my seniors to do this in QueryDSL and JPA without using any native queries.

Comment: Well, what's taking all the time then? Have you profiled your query?

Comment: I don't have issue with above mentioned time as its purely sql query execution, but is their any way I can cache this result for better performance of consecutive requests.

Comment: How about putting an index on the `name` column?

Comment: **Thank you**  ! I think that can work,. can you suggest me any good example or tutorial link for indexing purpose.

Comment: Found a way to make JPA 2 indexing columns. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing an index on that `NAME` column:

```
CREATE INDEX solve_all_problems ON entry_entity (name);
```

This works well because an index pre-orders all your data as it is a ordered data structure, so the database no longer needs to do any ordering work when you run a query like the one you're running right now. [Use-the-index-luke has a nice explanation on this topic](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by).

Side note: Be careful with adding indexes. While they drastically speed up read operations, each index will slow down write operations on that column. Each index is a tradeoff.